# Why did Mongoose ORM choose not to use regular mongo syntax for finding, sorting, etc?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've found that Mongoose syntax isn't very well documented yet where as Mongo docs are much better. Just wondering what the advantage of the changes are so I can take full advantage of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've found that Mongoose syntax isn't very well documented yet where as Mongo docs are much better.

The MongoDB documentation is maintained by the paid staff at [10gen](http://10gen.com/). 10gen is also the primary maintainer of several major drivers (C#, PHP, Java, Ruby, etc.)

However, looking at the MongoDB [node.js page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/node.JS), all of these products are currently community-supported. So they are maintained by a different set of people who may not be getting paid for their work.

[Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) is a relatively new product, so let's not be too hard on them :)

> Why did Mongoose ORM choose not to use regular mongo syntax for finding, sorting, etc?

It looks like Mongoose is trying to be an "ORM" (or ODM) over top of the existing drivers. ORMs don't always implement all of the same features.

However, I'm not the expert here. Mongoose has a relatively active [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-orm). That may be the best place to answer this question.